# .htaccess how to check if request was for specific file name and file not exists?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am trying to check if incoming request was for non existing file name and if requested file name was ending on _all.css ?

I have some code like below

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule \.css$ getLatest.php [L]
```

and that works if file not exists, but I would like to execute this condition only if requested file name was ending at the _all.css , how to concatenate this with this second condition ?

Thanks for all tips !

I tried some htaccess rules but I am not familiar how to concatenate them :(

Answer (score 0):

Change your last rule with the requested file name ending :

```
RewriteRule _all\.css$ getLatest.php [L]
```

But be careful, it's also css that will be loaded by the browser, and not another html page...